# How to dynamically calculate the fields in array of objects for a particular name filed in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

My code works fine to calculate various perks for towns.
But I want to dynamically calculate other fields values as well.

```js
var obj = [{
  "Town": "Newton",
  "PropertyType": "Multi Family",
  "InvestmentType": "Homeownership",
  "Perks": "Retail Store"
}, {
  "Town": "South Surrey",
  "PropertyType": "Multi Family",
  "InvestmentType": "Investment Property",
  "Perks": "Retail Store"
}, {
  "Town": "South Surrey",
  "PropertyType": "Multi Family",
  "InvestmentType": "Investment Property",
  "Perks": "Bus Station"
}, {
  "Town": "South Surrey",
  "PropertyType": "Condo",
  "InvestmentType": "Homeownership",
  "Perks": "Retail Store"
}];

var result = Object.values(obj.reduce(
  (a, { Town, Perks }) => { a[Town] = a[Town] || { Town, perks: {} };
  a[Town].perks[Perks] = (a[Town].perks[Perks] || 0) + 1;
  return a;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 0):

On each iteration destructure the object, and get the `Town`, and the rest of properties. Get the entries of the other properties, and iterate it with `Array.forEach()`. As you did for `Town` create the object for the property key and value as needed, and increment the count.

```js
const obj=[{"Town":"Newton","PropertyType":"Multi Family","InvestmentType":"Homeownership","Perks":"Retail Store"}, {"Town":"South Surrey","PropertyType":"Multi Family","InvestmentType":"Investment Property","Perks":"Retail Store"}, {"Town":"South Surrey","PropertyType":"Multi Family","InvestmentType":"Investment Property","Perks":"Bus Station"}, {"Town":"South Surrey","PropertyType":"Condo","InvestmentType":"Homeownership","Perks":"Retail Store"}];

const result = Object.values(obj.reduce((a, { Town, ...rest }) => {
  a[Town] = a[Town] || { Town };
  
  Object.entries(rest)
    .forEach(([k, v]) => {
      a[Town][k] = a[Town][k] || {};
      
      a[Town][k][v] = (a[Town][k][v] || 0) + 1;
    });
  
  return a;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: "Retail Store" is under perks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for something like that ?

```js
const obj = 
  [ { Town: 'Newton',       PropertyType: 'Multi Family', InvestmentType: 'Homeownership',       Perks: 'Retail Store' } 
  , { Town: 'South Surrey', PropertyType: 'Multi Family', InvestmentType: 'Investment Property', Perks: 'Retail Store' } 
  , { Town: 'South Surrey', PropertyType: 'Multi Family', InvestmentType: 'Investment Property', Perks: 'Bus Station'  } 
  , { Town: 'South Surrey', PropertyType: 'Condo',        InvestmentType: 'Homeownership',       Perks: 'Retail Store' } 
  ]
    
const ventil = (arr, Key, ...elms) => Object.values(arr.reduce((a,c) =>
  {
  a[c[Key]] = (a[c[Key]] ?? { [Key]:c[Key] } )
  elms.forEach(detail=>
    {
    a[c[Key]][detail] = a[c[Key]][detail] ?? {} 
    a[c[Key]][detail][c[detail]] = (a[c[Key]][detail][c[detail]] ?? 0) + 1
    })
  return a
  },{}))
  
console.log( 'result1 =', ventil(obj, 'Town', 'Perks' ) )
console.log( 'result2 =', ventil(obj, 'Town', 'Perks', 'PropertyType'))
console.log( 'result3 =', ventil(obj, 'Perks', 'Town', 'InvestmentType'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```